# What happened at the end of Nanana's Buried Treasure?

Tags: nananas-buried-treasure

At the very end of *Nanana's Buried Treasure*, after the ed, Isshin's holding a blood-tainted student card of Saki while Saki's standing outside the door with something black quickly crawling around her neck, murmuring 'I don't want to die'.
What's happening?

[image]

[image]

[image]